# Strange Dependency Behavior in VS.NET 2005 (Unnecessary .CPP Compilation)

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I work on a large Visual C++ (MFC) project in VS.NET 2005.

I have noticed strange behavior in Visual C++ 2005. Often, I will change one line of code in a .CPP file but many .CPP files will compile as a result of this. I have never seen this until VS.NET 2005. Theortically, changing a line of code in a .CPP file should simply require recompilation of that .CPP file and re-linking of the PE file.

What am I not understanding about the build process.

Comment: I've seen the same thing. We also get strange relinking of two projects each time the IDE launches the application. This did not happen in VC++ 2003 and earlier and seems to have stopped in VC++ 2008. I'll try to dig up the MSDN article about the bugs in 2005 that could explain.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this link](http://untidy.net/blog/2006/07/10/vs-always-builds/) helpful when solving a similar problem, was under pressure at the time, I tried a few things and the issue went away, for the life of me I don't know (or can't remember) which - if any - helped.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

This is a strange bug in the VS2005 dependency behavior. To find out one suggestion would be to take the following steps:

1. Go to **Tools** **-> Options ->
   Projects and Solutions -> Build and
   Run -> MSBuild Project Build output
   Verbosity** and select **Detailed**
2. Compile your project.

This will give you a detailed output of the build which **"may"** help you arrive at a solution to your problem.

Comment: VC++ 2005 doesn't use MSBuild to build, right? I think this setting will have to effect on VC++. I tried it and my build output was no different.

Comment: VC++ 2005 and 2008 _don't_ use MSBuild, so this setting won't have any effect.